# iOS app runs in simulator, ad-hoc distribution crash on launch

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, memory, adhoc

My iOS app runs correctly in the simulator and debugging device but when running on an ad-hoc allocated device, the app crashes and according to the app called "console" the app crashes with signal 9, killed 9 and also the app is killed with for termination assertion.  I'm lost at this point as what to do.  Let me know if you need more information.

Here's the link to the code:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/ch48v8uiyx7wiqh/Animal.zip

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Besides the other answers, which are good suggestions, a common root cause of this problem is that the Debug configuration can sometimes mask dangling pointer memory bugs. Do the following:

- Run the app in the simulator with release configuration. If it crashes. . .
- Use log statements and reruns to narrow in on the cause (debugger won't be available).

Comment: There were no issues when the app was run under the release configuration.  Do you think this may be a certificate issue?

Comment: I'm sorry - not sure what else it might be. . A certificate problem sounds plausible

Comment: Actually, I do have a crash log.  Please look at it here:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/e7sl3zox2ebo1fm/ReportCrash%20%201-10-14%2C%201-43%20PM.crash